# Perl script: modification to avoid necessity of user input

Tags: perl

I use the following code to make a pdf file from jpgs. It works fine but what I would like to achieve is to modify this script so that it could be used without any user input. I would like to right click a folder in Windows choose this script and have a pdf made. So this script needs to get a folder name and create a pdf file without asking for its name. It would be perfect if the name of final pdf would be the same as the folder where jps are. Could you help me, please?

The registry key is as follows:

"C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" "D:\test\790024.pl" %1

Here comes the code:

```
#!usr/bin/perl -w
    use strict;
    use PDF::API2;
    #concatenates image files of type JPEG, GIF, and PNG in a specific directory into a pdf file that will
    #be spit out into that same directory upon completion

    #very fun


    print "Input a filepath to a directory (ending with a /. ex: 'C:/path/to/dir/'): ";
    my $dir = <STDIN>;
    chomp $dir;
    print "\nInput the name for the pdf file you wish to create (ex: 'pictures'): ";
    my $pdf_name = <STDIN>;
    chomp $pdf_name;

    #grab a list of files in our very special directory.
    my @images = sort glob("$dir*") or die "No images\n";

    #xreate a new document with no pages
    my $pdf = PDF::API2->new;

    #loop through our images, create a page for each image
    # - while adding the image to the created page -> this is done in the subs
    for my $file (@images){
        #call sub based on what regex matches 
        add_jpg($file) if ($file =~ /.jpg/);
        #add_png($file) if ($file =~ /\.png$/);
        #add_png($file) if ($file =~ /.png/);
        #add_gif($file) if ($file =~ /.gif/);

    }

    $pdf->saveas("$dir$pdf_name.pdf");


    #subs 
    sub add_jpg{
        my $jpg = shift;
        my $image = $pdf->image_jpeg($jpg);
        my $page = $pdf->page();
        $page->mediabox(0,0,$image->width, $image->height);
        $page->trimbox(0,0,$image->width, $image->height);
        my $gfx = $page->gfx;
        $gfx->image($image, 0, 0);

    }

    sub add_png{
        my $png = shift;
        my $image = $pdf->image_png($png);
        my $page = $pdf->page();
        $page->mediabox(0,0,$image->width, $image->height);
        $page->trimbox(0,0,$image->width, $image->height);
        my $gfx = $page->gfx;
        $gfx->image($image, 0, 0);
    }

    sub add_gif{
        my $gif = shift;
        my $image = $pdf->image_gif($gif);
        my $page = $pdf->page();
        $page->mediabox(0,0,$image->width, $image->height);
        $page->trimbox(0,0,$image->width, $image->height);
        my $gfx = $page->gfx;
        $gfx->image($image, 0, 0);
    }
```

Comment: It works only when a command line is open and when I paste a path to JPGs ending with / . I created a key in Windows registry to have a right menu on every folder which would allow me to right click and have a pdf made. They key is as follows: "C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" "D:\test\790024.pl" %1 . If I follow your solution, it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the @ARGV array to grab parameters for the command line.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use PDF::API2;
use strict;

# assume all just one directory path
my $folder = join(' ', @ARGV);

# deal with dos paths
$folder =~ s|\\|/|g;

$folder =~ s|/$||;

my $pdf_file = $folder . '.pdf';

die "Not a folder!\n" unless -d $folder;
die "There's already a pdf of that name!\n" if -f $pdf_file;

my $pdf = PDF::API2->new;

opendir DIR, $folder;
while(my $file = readdir DIR) {
    next unless $file =~ /\.je?pg$/i;
    my $jpg = $folder . '/' . $file;

    my $image = $pdf->image_jpeg($jpg);
    my $page = $pdf->page();
    $page->mediabox(0,0,$image->width, $image->height);
    $page->trimbox(0,0,$image->width, $image->height);
    my $gfx = $page->gfx;
    $gfx->image($image, 0, 0);
}
close DIR;

$pdf->saveas($pdf_file);
```

Comment: Thank you for your great improvement. It almost does the trick but if there is a space character in the name of a folder, the script fails to work. Could you fix this, please?

Comment: @menteith If a space character breaks the script, I would say that your way of passing the directory name to the script is broken, and you have to fix that, probably by quoting the directory name.  If have no idea about how these things work in windows, though.

Comment: You need to change the registry key to: "C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" "D:\test\790024.pl" "%1"

Comment: Thanks for this. It still does not work. Without a space it work flawlessly. Please have a look at this (command line output): D:\test>790024.pl "space character"
Can't call method "val" on an undefined value at C:/strawberry/perl/lib/PDF/API2
/Resource/XObject/Image.pm line 66.

Comment: @MJWalsh Just noticed that the script makes a pdf even if there are no JPGs in a folder. Is it possible to avoid it and do not make a pdf when a folder is empty or there is no JPGs in it? Thanks for your work again.

Comment: And also when the file extension is uppercase (i.e. JPG) the script does not work.

Comment: @MJWalsh Now when extension is uppercase everyting works just fine! It would be great if the script would not produce pdf if a directory is empty of there are no jpgs there. Now script makes pdf even if a directory is empty.